# Git show doesn't return commit message

Tags: github, sh

I am trying to use following git command to get git commit for last 25 mins in reverse chronological order via shell script.

`git rev-list --since="25 minutes ago" --no-merges HEAD`

And then I iterate over each commit and extract commit message like below

```
for i in $(git rev-list --since="25 minutes ago" --no-merges HEAD)
do
    COMMIT_MESSAGE="$(git show -s --pretty=format:"%b" $i)"
    echo $COMMIT_MESSAGE
done
```

But for some reason, it's giving me blank message.

Not sure what am I missing here.

Appreciate any thoughts for the same.

Comment: It seems that `%b` is the culprit. The body is not returning commit message. `%s` works well here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the [`pretty-format %b`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-embem) is empty, try `%B`, for the full raw subject+body.
And try `git log` instead of `git show -s`

Check also if the pager is an issue here, by [removing it](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--P):

```
git -P log -1 --pretty=format:%b "%i"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will definitely try it. It's late night here. Will try tomorrow morning and update here.